# How to do validation for mobile websites with javascript

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a mobile website using Codeigniter and Mysql. Development got completed

Now i want to do some validations. I tried Jquery validation controls and javascript validation controls with innerhtml but both are not working in the mobile browser.

The validations part is working fine when comes to desktop version.

How to do validation for mobile websites. please suggest me anyother possible solutions

Thanks

Comment: What is your current validation? Post your code please or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you checked it some other mobile browser as maybe this is the issue with your mobile browser js support